# a function in .bash_profile

Tags: linux, bash

I try to write a function in .bash_profile to define a function for process killing as follows:

```
function pkill {
                pid = ps -elf|grep python|grep $1|awk -F " " '{print $4}'
                kill -9 pid
}
```

And what I want to do is using "pkill keyword" to kill the process that pid=[ps -elf|grep python|grep keyword|awk -F " " '{print $4}'],and my code didn't work.How should I write this function?

about kill:
my python process is multithreaded.I've tried `kill pid`,`kill -TERM pid`,or`kill -INT pid`,but still can find it in the processlist.So I used 'kill -9'.

Comment: just a sidenode: do you have a system command `pkill` (http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) available on your system?

Comment: Please don't use `kill -9`: http://aplawrence.com/SCOFAQ/FAQ_scotec6killminus9.html and http://sial.org/howto/shell/kill-9/ and http://speculation.org/garrick/kill-9.html

Comment: @akira:oops,there is one already:0

Comment: @Dennis Williamson:That's right.Thanks for your advice.

Comment: upvoting needs 15 reputation?o_o

Comment: there you have some reputation upvotes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pid=$(ps -elf|grep vim|grep 'screenrc' | awk -F" " '{print $4}')
```

But you might be able to use **pgrep** instead:

```
pid=$(pgrep -f "python .*$1")
```

or

```
pids=$(pgrep -d' ' -f "python .*$1")
kill -9 $pids
```

If you're feeling confident (reckless!):

```
\pkill -9 -f "python .*$1"
```

Comment: Or just `pkill -f "python .*$1"`, as `pkill` always comes with `pgrep`.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you're listing and then discarding a ton of extra junk?

(I assume you're using GNU ps, but I prefer BSD ps syntax. It's supported by GNU ps, too, because GNU ps supports everything.)

```
 # as others have noted 'pkill' is an existing command, so let's not clash with its name
 function pypkill {
      pids=$(ps ax -opid= -ocomm= | grep python | grep "$1" | awk -F " " '{print $1}')
      kill -TERM $pids
 }
```

Breakdown:

- pids=

  - The sub shell may return more than one PID. This captures all of them
- $( )

  - a subshell. Commands inside the parentheses will be executed and their output returned in place.
- ps ax

  - shows all processes on the system (BSD syntax)
- -opid= -ocomm=

  - tells ps to output two columns: PID and command name, and to ommit the header line
- kill -TERM $pids

  - Using kill -9 is a last resort. In most cases kill -TERM is what you want, or possibly kill -INT, before resorting to kill -KILL.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be more like

```
  pid=$(ps -elf|grep python|grep $1|awk -F" " '{print $4}')
  kill -9 $pid
```

Comment: It seems still not work,error info said: bad substitution.:(

Comment: @SpawnST: Sorry, I don't have bash here to try it out, I was just guessing. :(

Comment: remove the space between -F and " "

Comment: It should be `$( )`, not `${ }`.